# How to recursively create nested Azure Management Groups using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-management-groups

I am trying to create nested management groups recursively in Terraform and I can't seem to be able to achieve it using count or for or for_each. The best I have been able to achieve is to filter Tenant level and non-tenant level groups but that would still not help me create them recursively.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

```
locals {
  managementGroups = [
    {
      id          = "MainGroupOne"
      displayName = "Main Group One"
      parent      = "Tenant Root Group"
    },
    {
      id          = "MainGroupTwo"
      displayName = "Main Group Two"
      parent      = "Tenant Root Group"
    },
    {
      id          = "GroupOne"
      displayName = "Group One"
      parent      = "MainGroupOne"
      subscriptions = [
        "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", "YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY"
      ]
    },
    {
      id          = "ChildOne"
      displayName = "Child One"
      parent      = "GroupOne"
      subscriptions = [
        "ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
      ]
    },
    { id          = "GroupTwo"
      displayName = "Group Two"
      parent      = "MainGroupOne"
    },
    { id          = "GroupThree"
      displayName = "Group Three"
      parent      = "MainGroupTwo"
    }
  ]
}

locals {
  rootGroups = [
    for grp in local.managementGroups : grp
    if grp.parent == "Tenant Root Group"
  ]

  nonRootGroups = [
    for grp in local.managementGroups : grp
    if grp.parent != "Tenant Root Group"
  ]
}

output "rootGroups" {
  value = local.rootGroups
}

output "nonRootGroups" {
  value = local.nonRootGroups
}

resource "azurerm_management_group" "root_groups" {
  count = length(local.rootGroups)

  name             = local.rootGroups[count.index].id
  display_name     = local.rootGroups[count.index].displayName
}

resource "azurerm_management_group" "nonroot_groups" {
  count = length(local.nonRootGroups)

  name         = local.nonRootGroups[count.index].id
  display_name = local.nonRootGroups[count.index].displayName

  ############### PROBLEM AREA ###############
  # parent_management_group_id = ?
  ############### PROBLEM AREA ###############
}
```

*Edit:* I want to achieve something like this but without hardcoding anything in the config itself.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by creating them "recursively"? Its not very clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I have edited the question and added a screenshot of what I would like to achieve. I started off with something more on these lines but ended up with what I posed above.

Comment: locals {
  managementGroups = [
    {
      id            = "MainGroupOne"
      displayName   = "Main Group One"
      subscriptions = []
      children = [
        {
          id          = "GroupOne"
          displayName = "Group One"
          subscriptions = [
            "XXX"
          ]
          children = [
            {
              id          = "ChildOne"
              displayName = "Child One"
              subscriptions = [
                "YYY"
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You cannot have an infinite number of management group levels on Azure. As per doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview#important-facts-about-management-groups), the maximum is up to 6 excluding the root mgt group. Why not create them with JSON objects of 6 levels or less?

Answer (score -2):

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

locals {
    tenant_root_group_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.tenant_id}"
}
```