# Are recursive modules even a possibility in Terraform?

Tags: recursion, terraform

Are recursive modules even a possibility in Terraform?

I want to create a module called `my_module` with the below content

```
variable "name" {
  type = "string"
}

variable "children" {
  type = list(object)
}

resource "XXX" "example_resource" {
  name = var.name
}

module "example_recursion" {
  source = "../my_module"

  count = length(var.children)

  name = var.children[count.index].name
}
```

When I do init it seems to get itself in a twist and ends up corrupting the module cache!

```
Initializing modules...
- name in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module
- name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion in ../modules/my_module

Error: Failed to remove local module cache
│ 
│ Terraform tried to remove
│ .terraform/modules/name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion
│ in order to reinstall this module, but encountered an error: unlinkat
│ .terraform/modules/name.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion.example_recursion:
│ file name too long
```

Comment: No, they are not possible.

Comment: Any idea why they aren't possible? Is it just a limitation of Terraform? Seems very counterintuitive!

Comment: Don't know. You can always try other IoT tools. Terraform is one of many.

Comment: But why do you need recurstion? Usually iteration is more then enough for all terraform usecases.

Comment: Trying to create management groups in Azure without hardcoding anything. You responded to the question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212294/how-to-recursively-create-nested-azure-management-groups-using-terraform?noredirect=1#comment129304401_73212294

Comment: I see. Sadly I didn't have time to time more on your previous question.

Comment: Recursion is possible in declarative languages (although rare compared to iteration as mentioned previously), but you are recursively declaring/initializing, which is not allowed in any of the thirty or so languages with which I am familiar.